# Microphone issue in audio streaming using FFMPEG

Tags: windows-xp, ffmpeg, streaming, microphone, audio-streaming

I executed the command

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

to find out that the audio device is Realtek HD Audio Input. But executing the command

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Realtek HD Audio Input" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -re -f rtp://10:14:35:12:1234
```

gives the error
  "Could not find audio device. audio='Microphone (Realtek HD Audio Input: Input/output error"

I have checked for the working of the microphone and it works well. Please let me know what is the issue here.

The machine runs on Windows-XP SP2.

Comment: Please include the full, uncut ffmpeg console output for both commands.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try :

> ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="**Realtek HD Audio Input**" -acodec
>   libmp3lame -ab 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -re -f rtp://10:14:35:12:1234